# Android - Change app Theme on onClick

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, themes

i know there is a way to change the app default theme on button click. Blackmart developers have done it. I’ve already searched Google like 1000 pages but i found just this (not working)

```
getApplication().setTheme(Theme.Holo)
```

As i already created a new style in res/values/styles.xml is there any other way to dynamically change it? Even rebooting the application?

Comment: This code will work if you put it before setContentView(), but to change it on click, try setTheme() then setContentView() after it

Comment: are you calling `setContentView(View);` again after calling `setTheme()`?

Comment: Follow this link. It has exactly what you need! [Using Themes in Android Applications](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) **EDIT** Also check this question too! [Switching application-wide theme programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically)

Comment: Tried to put setTheme and then setContentView but nothing changed… I can see that android taked the onClick in log cat...

Comment: can you try re launching the activity after the `setTheme()`? just to see if that works..

Comment: Try removing getApplication() (just setTheme())

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar nope… doesn’t work

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah Doesn’t work either...

Comment: this might help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612062/implement-change-black-light-theme-feature-in-android-app

Answer (score 70):

Following blog can solve your problem:

http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837

Copying the blog code for quick reference:

Assuming that you already defined following three themes in the XML file `R.style.FirstTheme`, `R.style.SecondTheme` and `R.style.ThirdTheme`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class ChangeThemeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
          findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
          findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          switch (v.getId())
          {
          case R.id.button1:
          Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_DEFAULT);
          break;
          case R.id.button2:
          Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_WHITE);
          break;
          case R.id.button3:
          Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_BLUE);
          break;
          }
     }
}
```

Let us write the below code in the "Utils" file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
public class Utils
{
     private static int sTheme;
     public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
     public final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
     public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
     /**
      * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type.
      */
     public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
     {
          sTheme = theme;
          activity.finish();
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
     }
     /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
     public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
     {
          switch (sTheme)
          {
          default:
          case THEME_DEFAULT:
              activity.setTheme(R.style.FirstTheme);
              break;
          case THEME_WHITE:
              activity.setTheme(R.style.SecondTheme);
              break;
          case THEME_BLUE:
              activity.setTheme(R.style.Thirdheme);
              break;
          }
     }
}
```

Hope it helps...

EDIT 1:

following is the reason `AlertDialog` does not take custom theme:

Implementation in Builder.create() is:

```
public AlertDialog create() {
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(P.mContext);
    P.apply(dialog.mAlert);
    [...]
}
```

which calls the "not-theme-aware" constructor of AlertDialog, which looks like this:

```
protected AlertDialog(Context context) {
    this(context, com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert);
}
```

There is a second constructor in AlertDialog for changing themes:

```
protected AlertDialog(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
    [...]
}
```

that the Builder just doesn't call.

Check out following post for more relevant fixes..

[How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Following is the most voted answer:

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog))
```

Comment: Yeah, saw this morning… not working either because of List View…

Comment: what is the problem with the `ListView`..? are you able to change theme for all other view (except `ListView`) using this method?

Comment: are you using `ListActivity`?

Comment: Yes for some other reasons… Oh, i noticed that it doesn’t change in a custom DialogAlert view… :(

Comment: check out the most voted answer in following post..

Comment: check out my edit 1 for `AlertDialog` issue..

Comment: just solved AlertDialog issue, now the problem is the ListActivity… I think i’ll take Pavlos’ suggestion…Thank you for your hard work Praful… You can take a look at my app and if I’ve done it at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LCPInt.lcpintappsupportchecker Thank you!!!

Comment: Very good answer. Should have much more votes.

Comment: Just to add something from above answer. Please note that Activity is deprecated and android is now using AppCompatActivity. So replace activity with AppCompatActivity. e.g.
`changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)` change to `changeToTheme(AppCompatActivity activity, int theme)`
Then you can say:
`activity.recreate()`