# Android Java change theme in program

Tags: java, android, themes, switch-statement

How can I change the the theme of my Android application from light to dark programmatically?
I've tried something like:

```
 setTheme(R.style.Holo_Theme_Light);
```

but I found nothing which worked for me.

Comment: Are you doing it before calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the first line in onCreate, before calling   `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` as it is where view processing takes place and your change should be before that to be included in view creation

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Holo_Theme_Light);  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Also, please refer to [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) to know where to call your setTheme

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here: [Android - Change app Theme on onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301554/android-change-app-theme-on-onclick)
I am sorry it's not a comment but I don't have enough reputation :(

EDIT - You can't use the setTheme before the superoncreate, if you will call it before the superoncreate it will work, like here: [Change Activity's theme programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562051/change-activitys-theme-programmatically)

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576546/3168859)

It says

As [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) say you have to call setTheme before any view output. It seems that super.onCreate() takes part in view processing.

So, to switch between themes dynamically you simply need to call setTheme before super.onCreate like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

So, **make sure you have put `setTheme(R.style.Holo_Theme_Light);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your code**