# Notification using setFullScreenIntent() for BigTextStyle opening Activity automatically

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I have a very strange issue, I am working on Push Notification and it was successfully implemented but when i have used BigTextStyle in Notification to show a long message in notification area with setFullScreenIntent() method then the issue coming up the Notification opening the Activity automatically which is set in PendingIntent.

If I don't use setFullScreenIntent() then notification won't opening Activity automatically the user has to tap or click on Notification to open the Activity set in PendingIntent.

So there are two codes

1. Without setFullScreenIntent() working fine and not opening Activity automatically:

   ```
   notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                           .setContentTitle("Title")
                           .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                           .setContentText(message)
                           .setStyle(
                                   new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                           .bigText(message))
                           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                           .setAutoCancel(true);
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               manager.notify(1, notification.build());
   ```
2. With setFullScreenIntent() also working fine but opening Activity automatically:-

   ```
   notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                           .setContentTitle("Title")
                           .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                           .setContentText(message)
                           .setStyle(
                                   new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                           .bigText(message))
                           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                           .setFullScreenIntent(resultPendingIntent, true) //Whether true or false same result
                           .setAutoCancel(true);
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               manager.notify(1, notification.build());
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## public NotificationCompat.Builder setFullScreenIntent (PendingIntent intent, boolean highPriority)
>
> An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status
> bar. Only for use with extremely high-priority notifications demanding
> the user's immediate attention, such as an incoming phone call or
> alarm clock that the user has explicitly set to a particular time. If
> this facility is used for something else, please give the user an
> option to turn it off and use a normal notification, as this can be
> extremely disruptive.
>
> On some platforms, the system UI may choose to display a heads-up
> notification, instead of launching this intent, while the user is
> using the device.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *intent:*    The pending intent to launch.
>
> *highPriority:*  Passing
> true will cause this notification to be sent even if other
> notifications are suppressed.

Found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)). As you can see it immediately launches the intent. I don't really know in what case you wanted to use `setFullScreenIntent()`?

A notification won't automatically expand when a static notification is displayed on top (could be custom bar with wifi, bluetooth and sound control)

Comment: I have already read the android documentation and in code i have specified if i use true or false its opening activity. I want expanded notification view whenever notification shows in notification area. Is there anything else, i have read about InboxStyle but its also not expanding automatically. user have to drag the notification message to expand it.

Comment: @Clairvoyant Okay, I'm not quite sure what you want. The notification message is automatically expanded when it's on the top. Else it won't be expanded. Do you want the new HeadsUp from lollipop? (Where you see the message in the top of your screen instead of only in the statusbar)

Comment: not Heads Up message. When any notification shown in notification area then the default property of that notification is not expanded one. i want it to be expanded when shown in notification area

Comment: @Clairvoyant Do you have some sort of static notification? (like quick controls for wifi or a music player or something like that). Cause the default for a new notification is to be expanded. This behavior can not be modified. The only way it is not automatically expanded is when you have something above it like a static notification.

Comment: I have a notification of no simcard in the device in which i am developing

Comment: @Clairvoyant Try the notification on an emulator. You'll see the it is automatically expanded. That is the default behavior and has always been this way.

Comment: would check and reply back

Comment: I have checked it and now its showing expanded so is there anything we can do when there are static notification

Comment: @Clairvoyant I'm afraid not

Comment: I am not sure that what do you want with setFullScreenIntent, can you explain your problem i think you want to expand notification automatically with drag or touch events right ?

Comment: @Clairvoyant If you think my answer is correct. Could you mark it as correct?

Comment: @Clairvoyant Just did. I don't know. I had a static notification a long time and then realized it automatically expands when it was gone. So I know what it's like

Answer (score 0):

pass setFullScreenIntent and setContentIntent with different pending intents.

Worked for me. click on Notif will work and autolaunch will stop