# android theme using multiple colors.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors, android-theme

I am new to android development, so please bear with me. My app elements (button color, background color, text color, divider color etc.) uses colors from the colors.xml using "@color/mycolor" for example.

My colors.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="mycolor">#202020</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="whitehint">#50FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="primary">#673AB7</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#512DA8</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#D1C4E9</color>
    <color name="accent">#794cc9</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#a4a4a4</color>
    <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
</resources>
```

Now I have a menu where the user can select a different theme which I want to use a second colors2.xml for example which will have the same color names but a different hex code for the keys. How do I go about which xml file does my app references?

Comment: This is what color attributes are for. You have multiple themes and let's say that both have defined `<item name="colorAccent">something</item>` where *something* is a different color resource (`@color/some_color`) for each of the themes.

Comment: @EugenPechanec yes but in there, how do you specify a different colors.xml file? in the line, where do I specify to use colors2.xml in `<item name="colorAccent">something</item>`

Can you give a small example please?

Answer (score 10):

1. Let's suppose you already know how to switch themes on the fly.
2. You can have multiple XML files defining colors. `colors.xml` is just a convention. All these colors will be defined and accessible in parallel...
3. ...unless you put the file in a different resource bracket. E.g. default colors in `res/values/colors.xml` and colors for tablets in `res/values-sw600dp/colors.xml` (the file name is not important) which is probably not what you're going for.

Let's say you have these themes:

```
<style name="Theme.My.DarkRed" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#f00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#c00</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#c90</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.My.LightBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#9ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#6cc</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#06f</item>
</style>
```

Now when you define e.g. `android:background="?colorAccent"` the color appropriate for the theme you're using will be resolved.

Note: Sadly before Lollipop these color attr references could not be used in XML drawables.

#### How to access color references from outside of XML?

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{R.attr.colorPrimary, R.attr.colorAccent});
int colorPrimary = a.getColor(0);
int colorAccent = a.getColor(1);
a.recycle();
```

#### What attributes can be specified?

```
android:windowBackground

android:colorForeground
android:colorBackground

android:textColorPrimary 
android:textColorSecondary

colorPrimary <!-- without prefix in AppCompat, with prefix on pure Lollipop -->
colorPrimaryDark
colorPrimaryAccent
colorControlNormal
colorControlActivated
colorControlHighlight
colorButtonNormal

android:textColorHint
android:textColorLink
android:textColorHighlight

android:listDivider
```

et cetera, et cetera...

You can look into `Android\sdk\platforms\android-*\data\res\values\themes*.xml` and appcompat-v7 source for more attributes.

Then you can even define your own attrs (off-topic, use Google).

Comment: absolutely amazing, I want to buy you coffee!! this makes a lot more sense as now I can put the pieces together. thank you!!

Comment: You mentioned "Note: Sadly before Lollipop these color attr references could not be used in XML drawables." How do we achieve this in pre lollipop? all via java code?

Comment: The new `Context.getDrawable(int)` and `Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme)` are used to assign theme attrs to the drawable but these methods aren't present on earlier platforms. I believe a custom drawable inflater would be able to achieve this , but I don't know of any.

Comment: Now is better to use ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary) in order to access color

Comment: @Vaios Only if you actually define `<color name="colorPrimary">`. `TypedArray` is used to resolve attibutes defined in the theme (Theme `colorPrimary` may point to `R.color.whatever`.). Don't mix `R.color` and `R.attr`. `ContextCompat.getColor` will not resolve anything but `R.color`.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). You can set a custom theme to your app in the manifest.

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

And then when the user selects the menu option to change the theme, you should change the theme programmatically.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301554/android-change-app-theme-on-onclick) for dynamically changing the app theme.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I read the doc and tried a quick test. So I have the following in my styles.xml in the values folder:

`<style name="redtheme">
        <item name="android:color">#FF0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="purpletheme">
        <item name="android:color">#FF00FF</item>
    </style>`


If I want a text to use red or purple color based on which theme is selected, how do I specify which style to use and change the style?