# Android Java on toggle change color

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, toggle

How do I change the color/s in my styles.xml which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#FF9800</item>
</style>
```

when I toggle my ToggleButton in my activity_main.xml, which looks like this

```
    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Light Theme"
    android:textOff="Dark Theme"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

so far I have done this to make that behavior happen in my MainActivity.java

```
    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // check if toggle active
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

The reason is that I want to make a dark and a light theme for my app:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically change the appTheme. But there is a workaround.

Check out this link.

[Android - Change app Theme on onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301554/android-change-app-theme-on-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Themes are, unfortuantly, immutable, meaning that you can't change them programatically during runtime.

Nor can you simply set a style. You can, however, change the style by inflating a new view. You may find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code) useful.