# Change AppTheme instantly on clicked overflow menu?

Tags: android, overflow-menu, app-themes

I have to problems:

• When the user taps on the three dots (the overflow menu), I don't want the app to display a menu. Instead I want it to do an action instantly.

• The action should be a change to the AppTheme. So when the user taps on the overflow menu, the app theme changes to dark, if the user taps it again to light, etc.

Comment: Adding a different behavior to a well known part of the user interface reeks of a bad design choice. Is there a reason why you want the overflow menu *not* to be what it is?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak is completely correct.  It should be an icon that represents the action it does.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I know how to change the overflow menu icon and I'll change it to a palette icon, so everything's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not a good way or as @David Medenjak said, it might be a different design or bad design (*something like out of the rules*).

By the way, you can use this for handling that `OverflowMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

   if (disableMenu())
      Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   return true;
}
```

And then use the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301723/4409113

Finally, use the following link for checking what the current theme is and at the end, set your theme.

Hope that helps.