# Change App Theme ColorPrimary, ColorPrimaryDark programmatically

Tags: android

I was to designed app which have 4 Tabs in MainActivity. Now I want to change App Theme color like as Google Play Store.

I was already see some solution like [setTheme() example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576546/8969251) and I was also found [This solution for dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301723/8969251) but it is also restarting activity!!

This all kind of solution not work as Google Play Store. Because I want change theme without restart or refreshing activity.

Comment: Why can't you try setTheme() method. are you using fragments as tab?

Comment: Yes! I am using fragments as tabs.

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496425/8867002)

Comment: Yes I already tried. See my question description deeply.

Comment: There is only option to apply setTheme() is restart or recreate activity. So, I am finding another way.